# Insert a single value into database table which has multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I couldn't find an anwser on google, so here's my question.
Let's say, I have a table which has name,lastName,Age columns.
What I want to do, is insert only "name" into the table.

I have a function

```
function c_mysqlInsert($ptable,$pvaluename,$pvalue,$database=""){
    global $con_dbaccounts;
    $dbname = ($database=="")?$con_dbaccounts:$database;
    $con = c_dbconnect($dbname);

    mysql_query($con,"INSERT INTO $ptable ($pvaluename) VALUES('$pvalue')");
}
/**
```

which doesn't seem to insert any new things into the $pdbtable, even when $ptable, $pvaluename and $database are all correct. It does connect to the database $database.

I thought it would create a new row with $pvalue and the other columns empty (or NULL), but it doesn't.

So I guess I can't do it this way - call c_mysqlInsert function multiple times to insert into all three columns, so is there any other way I could make this function work?

Comment: Did you bother checking the return value? No, you did not.

Comment: Look up variable scope. `$pdbtable` is not defined in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statement has the `$pdbtable` variable but the variable passed into your function is `$ptable`.  Change the variable in your insert and you should be golden.

Comment: Another 30minutes gone poof because of extra chars, I'm surprised I didn't get any errors though

Comment: I see you edited your post. Was it a typo in the post or did you find the problem yourself?

Comment: Actually, both. I didn't need the $con in query.